# Typescript: How to export a variable

Tags: typescript, import, module, export

I want to open 'file1.ts' and write:

```
export var arr = [1,2,3];
```

and open another file, let's say 'file2.ts' and access directly to 'arr' in file1.ts:

I do it by:

```
import {arr} from './file1';
```

However, when I want to access 'arr', I can't just write 'arr', but I have to write 'arr.arr'. The first one is for the module name. How do I access directly an exported variable name?

Comment: export [1, 2, 3] ?

Comment: Ummm. No. If you import the way you posted then `arr` is the array. Only if you import it like this: `import * as arr from "./file1"` then you'll need to use it like `arr.arr`

Comment: Well, that's how it is supposed to be, as stated in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and the [typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import). If it's not working for you then you're probably doing something else. Your code works just fine for me where `arr` is the array without the need to use `arr.arr`.

Answer (score 141):

There are two different types of export, **[named](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49123213/181569)** and **[default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43039044/181569)**.

You can have multiple named exports per module but only one default export.

For a named export you can try something like:

```js
// ./file1.ts
const arr = [1,2,3];
export { arr };
```

Then to import you could use the original statement:

```js
// ./file2.ts
import { arr } from "./file1";
console.log(arr.length); // 3
```

This will get around the need for `arr.arr` you mentioned.

> How do pirates know that they are pirates?
> They think, therefore they ARR!!

Answer (score 66):

If you do:

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
export default arr;
```

...

```
import arr from './file1';
```

Then it should work

Comment: In **file1** it could be `myArr` but should import `import arr from './file1'` to use as `arr` in **file2**

Comment: I prefer the named export like in the other solution.